# magnolia cms : Bootstrap failed while installing

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I got this problem when I installed magnolia cms on my PC. Here is the error message:

> Error while installing or updating standard-templating-kit module.
>   Task 'Bootstrap' failed. (ValueFormatException: not a valid date:
>   2012-02-09T14:47:08.216+01:00)

General message:

> Could not perform instal enter code herelation: Error importing
>   config.modules.standard-templating-kit.dialogs.generic.pages.tabChannels:
>   not a valid date: 2012-02-09T14:47:08.216+01:00)

I tried to search for this problem, but I can't find any answers. Please help me.

Comment: I thought we had found out in previous comments that the issue seemed to stem from a Jackrabbit utility class; org.apache.jackrabbit.util.ISO8601#parse, where the Timezone was "wrong". Without those comments I can't dig any further, but I thought I suggested you try and change the timezone on your computer and try again. I'd consider this a bug in Jackrabbit, but I can't reproduce it locally.

Comment: For the record, I asked if you could run the following and see if where the null was returned from. https://gist.github.com/gjoseph/26c36f0a678a874b306b

Comment: And if I recall correctly, it came from the line with the timezone check. Can you verify with https://gist.github.com/gjoseph/7c0c0ac16de46d12092c ? That said, I'm not sure why your setup wouldn't know about GMT+1...

Comment: yeah, original comments were on the answer which was deleted ... and with that the comments were lost, so here's what they were:
the result was "parse(2012-02-29T14:47:08.216+01:00): null".  But it should have been a Calendar instance. The "null" came from line 156.